# Handle isql Login failed in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, isql

I want to catch the login failed in my shell script

Code looks like below

```
retval=`isql -S$envServer -U$GCMS_USERNAME -h -b << ENDSQL | grep -vE "^Password: $"
$GCMS_PASSWORD
set nocount on
GO
USE "mydb"
GO
USE "SELECT tname from MYTABLE"
GO
ENDSQL`
echo retval
```

So if Login fails i get `Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1: Server 'MYSERVER': Login failed. CT-LIBRARY error: ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.`

I want to catch this, so when this error comes is do exit and if it is sucess i can perform my other operations.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test for the `Msg` string:

```
if [[ "${retval}" =~ "Msg" ]]
then
    # do stuff with error message (eg display to console, write to log file, etc)
    exit
fi
```

If the data from `MYTABLE` could contain the string `Msg` you can expand the test to a pattern that's sufficiently unique to match on just errors:

```
regex='Msg.*Level.*State'

if [[ "${retval}" =~ ${regex} ]]                # do *NOT* wrap ${regex} is double quotes otherwise the quotes will be processed literally
then
    # do stuff with error message (eg display to console, write to log file, etc)
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Every bash command has an exit code. "0" is good, anything else means the last run command errored. Therefore, you can check if it failed by adding this after the `isql` command:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  # Do something about it
fi
```

Comment: This returns 0 in all cases. Since we want to capture isql failure $? doesnt work. it returns 0 in all cases